# How much bitcoin can be mined with intel core i5 pc with external graphic card?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-profitability, mining-hardware

I know ant miner is required to earn some cash, but am curious to know that how much bitcoin can be mined per day with a pc if it has the configuration like :

processor= Intel Core i5 6600K 3.50GHz 6th Gen. Processor

motherboard= MSI B150M Mortar DDR4 6th Gen. LGA1151 Socket Mainboard

ram= Twinmos 8GB DDR4 2400 BUS

graphics card= MSI GTX 950 2GB

-Thanks.

Comment: It is effectively zero. The days of GPU mining are long past, sorry.

Comment: sorry to know that, so the x11 coins can be mined beside cryptonote coins ?

Answer (score -1):

Less than the money that it will cost to you for sure.

I think It would take you a bunch of nights to get the minimun to get paid by the mining pool so you could even earn 0 Bitcoins.